# How can I delete a file that is in $RECYCLE.BIN but not in my recycle bin?

Tags: windows-10, recycle-bin

On an external drive the $RECYCLE.BIN folder has files in it, but according to Windows the recycle bin is empty. Looking at the $RECYCLE.BIN folder with WizTree I think some are files from when the drive was attached to a different machine (now defunct) and probably have no owner. Others are files from the same machine before I updated from Windows 7 to 10.

I looked at the properties and tried the 'Restore' button but nothing seemed to happen.

I don't want these files and would like to delete them - but how can I do it please?

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=%24recycle.bin

Comment: Thanks @spikey_richie. For some reason that question wasn't suggested when I asked it.